# Why does my random string generator produce too short strings?

Tags: c++, string, random

I have written a simple function that returns a random string.

```
std::string cache::generateCacheName()
{
    static const char pool[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    std::string r;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, sizeof(pool) - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        r += pool[distr(eng)];
    return r;
}
```

However, sometimes it returns a string randomly shorter than 48 characters.

I already added the `- 1` behind the `sizeof(pool)` trying to avoid adding the null-terminator from `pool`, but that didn't change anything.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This is a good candidate for stepping through with your debugger to see what goes wrong, plus look at what you're actually adding to that string.

Comment: How did you determine that the string is shorter than 48 characters?

Comment: @PeteBecker By calling this method a bunch of times, approximately half of them end up too short, with wildly varying lengths.

Comment: you should always consider an empty string when indexing into a string.  so if `pool` is "", then `sizeof(pool)` is 1.  1-1 == 0, and `pool[0]` in that case is....

Comment: "... approximately half of them end up too short..." is not how you determined that the strings are ending up too short.

Comment: Your string contains '`\0`' which is sometimes selected.

Comment: side note: you're causing a TON of extra allocations by using `+=` inside the loop. I would highly suggest using the [string constructor that allocates the entire space at once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and then indexing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) given a string literal "123", the size is 4, because it's an array of 4 const characters, counting the null.

b) When you subtract 1 from that size, you get 3.

c) When you have an array of 3 elements, the 3rd element is at offset 2.

d) std::uniform_int_distribution is defined over the closed interval [a,b].  That is, up to *and including* both endpoints form a to b.

e) When you pick a random number and it happens to be the largest value in that interval (in this case, 3) you grab the trailing null byte from pool and insert it into your string.  You probably want a max value of 2, not 3.

Therefore, your string is short if it happens to select the largest number in your distribution. Perhaps your code would be clearer with strlen(pool)-1, as long as it isn't empty.

Comment: 0 is a valid character value in an object of type `std::string`. The loop looks fine, and creates a string object with 48 characters in it. You're probably right that the code that calls this function doesn't like embedded nul characters, but there is not enough information in the question to be certain.

Comment: @PeteBecker There is.  `sizeof(aStringEndingInANullTerminator) -1` is always going to be the null terminator.  Which is included in his distribution.

Comment: @zzxyz I think Pete's point is that a std::string is more "container like" than is usually intended, and it is perfectly valid to store embedded nulls in the middle of the string.  Its only a problem if you interpret those nulls to have more meaning than they actually do (which is common)  This is the problem I guess the OP is encountering.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes!  That point's always been academic for me given my heavy interaction with C code, but fair enough.  Apologies.

Comment: This is a perfect example of where a [`constexpr std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) would be a better choice than a `const char[]` [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4817f6ae9623026)